# Tomcat 404 Error on simple JSP webpage

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I have made a simple dynamic web project in eclipse with tomcat
When i run my index.jsp file it throws 404 error. Below is screenshot of my web project

[image: Project Hierarchy]

As you can see index.jsp is located inside Web Content Folder but it still show 404 error
Also when i run it on my firefox browser it raises same 404 error but localhost:8080 shows tomcat home page so its working fine

Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: The application is probably not deployed on your Tomcat server. Check that you have deployed it, and check the tomcat logs to make sure there's no error.

Comment: Maybe you could post the index.jsp class ? How do you run the index.jsp ? is it by running the project as a whole or you click on the index.jsp and select run ? Also verify if the application has been deployed in the server.

Comment: I run index.jsp file by right clicking > run as > run on server

Comment: @JB Nizet I didn't understand what you mean by deployed. please explain

Comment: A Java webapp doesn't run magically. It has to be deployed on a server (tomcat here). When deployed, Tomcat will check that it can deploy the app: is the web.xml file valid, are the necessary libraries available, etc. Your tomcat server in eclipse has to be configured to deploy the web appliication you're developing. IIRC, you do that by double-clicking or right-clicking the server, and choosing which projects are deployed on the server.

Comment: I have restarted the serve rand it works i still didn't understand what is the problem. Please tell me the application is already deployed in the previous case but why restarting of server solved the problem

Comment: Sometimes as JB said it may not have been correctly deployed reason being that the web.xml file was not valid. Restarting the server deletes old(maybe corrupted) files and generates new web files which are needed to run your app. I use glassfish and sometimes when i make very significant changes to my project, i restart the server to reflect or those changes correctly by generating new files based on them. Sometimes saving and running is not enough since it doesn't overwrite all the required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes as JB said it may not have been correctly deployed reason being that the web.xml file was not valid. Restarting the server deletes old(maybe corrupted) files and generates new web files which are needed to run your app. I use glassfish and sometimes when i make very significant changes to my project, i restart the server to reflect or those changes correctly by generating new files based on them. Sometimes saving and running is not enough since it doesn't overwrite all the required.

Comment: I need a simple answer form you there is no web.xml file in my project. I have not seen it in my project as in the above screenshot

Comment: exactly where web.xml file is located

Comment: How about looking inside the WEB-INF ?

Comment: Inside Web-INF folder i have only lib sub-directory nothing else
If i make the project by default options then will eclipse make the web.xml file or during creation of dynamic web project i have to enable some option so that eclipse will make web.xml in my project?

Answer (score 0):

*In Eclipse check the following properties.*

Go to the **Project Properties   ->  Deployment Assembly    -> /WebContent**, Check the source location of for deploying the JSP’s, here the path is **/WebContent**, this is the location where the JSP’s need to be added not in **/WEB-INF**

[image]

What this means is that you need to put the JSP's directly in **/WebContent**  directory not inside the **/WEB-INF** directory.

[image]